# Actionscript3 to Arduino: sending a 'newline' character after an array of integers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, serial-port, arduino, parseint

I want to send an array of integers from an as3 app I'm writing in Flash Pro, to an Arduino Uno which will use them to continuously position and re-position 5 servos. So sending 15 integers will position the 5 servos, then re-position them, then reposition them again, then loop back to the first position and so on. Then I would send a new array replacing the old one whenever I wanted to.

So I've got my tinkerproxy configured between them ok (thanks to Mike Chambers and others) and I've written both sides so they appear to work ok when interfacing with their serial monitors. But I can't get em talking to each other properly.

My problem is simple ... I think ... It's how to get as3 to send a 'newline' or some other 'end' signal with or after the array so that the Arduino sketch (using serialEvent and parseInt to get the integers when they are sent), on receiving it, can jump past parseInt and do something else - in this case go to the loop and control these pesky servos.

Probably far too much code attached and I hope somebody can help. I'm pretty inexperienced, you may have guessed....

ARDUINO

```
/* 
   this sketch developed from arduino Tutorials ReadASCIIString + SerialEvent
   serialEvent can receive an array - 'buff' - of values from serial monitor
   loop can get those values and print some of them to prove it
   but I can't get Flash Pro (as3) to send the array: something to do with end of message character?
*/
#include <Servo.h>

int buff[100];//an array to hold integers from serial(arbitrary larger than ever needed size)
int j; //used to increment serial integer receipt in serialEvent
int patternLength;//=# of integers delivered over serial port, if followed by E or newline

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.setTimeout(2147483647);//25 days! so parseInt doesn't default to sending zeros every second
Serial.println("ready to go");//prints ok
}

void loop()
{
   for(int i=0; i<patternLength-4; i=i+5)//feed sets of 5 integers into 5 servos then repeats
    Serial.println(buff[i]);//prints 1st, 5th, 10th etc integer then repeats
    delay(1000);//so I can see it happening slowly enough
}//loops indefinitely until serialEvent interrupts to send new buff array values

void serialEvent()
{
     while(Serial.available()>0)
     {
     buff[j] = Serial.parseInt();
 Serial.println(buff[j]);//prints all integers sent if eg ','sent after last one
 j++;


 //if (Serial.read() == '\n')//works if serial monitor is set to 'newline' on sending
 if (Serial.read() == 'E')//works if no 'newline' + sending eg 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10E

 //BUT how to send the equivalent of one of the above two 'endings' from Flash???
 //so that this part of the code executes
     {
     patternLength = j;  
     Serial.println("go to loop");
     j=0;//reset the index so next array sent replaces this one in 'buff' 
     }
 }
```

}

FLASH PRO ACTIONSCRIPT as3

```
/*
Simple Example that connects to an Arduino (via TinkerProxy) and sends
an array of integers for it to use. That doesn't work......

adapted from FlashBlink Created by Mike Chambers:

http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2010/08/04/getting-started-with-flash-and-arduino/
*/


import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.Socket;
//import flash.events.IOErrorEvent;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
//import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;
import flash.utils.Endian;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//my example of an array of integers I want to send to the arduino
var pattern:Array = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

//socket we will use to connect to TinkerProxy
var _socket:Socket;

//Address where TinkerProxy is located. Will usually be
//localhost / 127.0.0.1
var _proxyAddress:String = "127.0.0.1";

//port TinkerProxy is listening on
var _proxyPort:uint = 5331;

function onAddedToStage():void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

    //create a Sprite to add to the stage.
    //This will be a simple button
    var s:Sprite = new Sprite();

    //draw a green square in the Sprite
    s.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
    s.graphics.drawRect(0,0, 200,100);
    s.graphics.endFill();

    //Add Sprite to the display list
    addChild(s);

    //position it
    s.x = 50;
    s.y = 50;

    //listen for when the user clicks the Sprite
    s.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

    _socket = new Socket();

    //Register for socket events

    //socket connected
    _socket.addEventListener( Event.CONNECT, onConnect );           

    //socket closed
    _socket.addEventListener( Event.CLOSE, onClose );           

    _socket.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;

    //connect
    _socket.connect(_proxyAddress, _proxyPort);
}

//called when we connect to the proxy server
function onConnect(event:Event):void
{
    trace("Socket Connected");
}

//called when the user clicks the button on stage
function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("onClick");

    //make sure we are connected to the socket
    if(!_socket.connected)
    {
        //if not, don't do anything
        trace("You must be connected to send a command to the Arduino.");
        return;
    }

    var ENDOF:String = "E";

    for(var j:int = 0; j < pattern.length; j++)
        { 
        _socket.writeUTFBytes(pattern[j]); //send pattern array to Arduino
        trace(pattern[j]);//trace what I think I've just sent
        }
        //then send something as a last character - not an integer.
        _socket.writeUTFBytes(ENDOF);//send this string value to arduino
        trace("should have just sent an E, and sends an: " + ENDOF);
        //but how do I send this E conjoined to the last integer of the pattern array
        //so that Arduino responds by jumping out of serialEvent back to the loop?

        //flush the socket. Not really necessary, but here for forward compatibility.
        _socket.flush();
}

//called when the socket is closed
function onClose(event:Event):void
{
    trace("Socket Closed");
}

onAddedToStage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AS3 looks fairly spot on.  One minor point, in `onAddedToStage()` you're removing an event listener from the stage which you never registered for.  If you really want that code to only fire once the timeline is added to the stage, replace line 114 with with following:

`addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage)`

As for your Arduino code , I'm not versed in the language it uses (some sort of C?), so feel free to ignore the following if you know better.

- You didn't encapsulate your `for` loop on lines `22` thru `24`
- You started encapsulating your `while` loop on line `30`, but forgot to close it on line `34`
- You declared `j`, but didn't initialized its value until line `44` after it was to be used in your `while` loop on line `33`.

Finally, to answer your core question.  You're already aware a newline is written as `\n`, so it would seem you're having difficulty reading this from `Serial.read()`.  [After reading the documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read), I couldn't find any datatype it comes out as, so I'm assuming you're dealing with either a ByteArray or a String.  Assuming it's a string, my first instinct would be to just split it into an Array with String.split(), but that's not a function available to String API.  [Others (however) have written it](http://www.esologic.com/?p=201), and I believe it would simplify the issue, assuming Strings & Ints can happily co-exist in those object types.

Conversely, since you already know the size of these numbers come in quintets, rather than use a `while` loop (line `29`), you could just use a `for` as follows:

```
#include <Servo.h>

int buff[100];
int j;
int patternLength;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.setTimeout(2147483647);
    Serial.println("ready to go");
}

void loop() {
    for(int i=0; i<patternLength-4; i=i+5) {
        Serial.println(buff[i]);
        delay(1000);
    }
}

void serialEvent() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        // This gaurantees we only pull the first 15 Ints into our buff array
        for (int k=0; k<15; k++)  {
            buff[j] = Serial.parseInt();
            Serial.println(buff[j]);
            j++;
        }

        patternLength = j;  
        Serial.println("go to loop");
        j=0;//reset the index so next array sent replaces this one in 'buff'
    }
}
```

If the above misses the mark for you, you may want to debug the value you're actually reading from the Stream and testing for in your if statement on line `37` with:

```
Serial.println("Reading: " + Serial.read());
```

Hope it helps.

-Cheers

Comment: I see I'm supposed to avoid comments like 'thanks', but hey: thanks. It's gonna take me a few days to go through this probably....then I'll come back with something legit!

Comment: Arduino is based on Processing. Brackets were necessary there. I think 'while' not 'for' allows iteration with parseInt, but the 'while' loop needs an 'exit' character or it stalls at parseInt. Unless it sees eg '100E', eg if it's '100,E', parseInt just hangs at the ',' waits 25 days then returns '0'. The arrays could be from 5 to 50 or more integers, so there's no fixed length property I can use to jump beyond parseInt. I made the last object in the Flash array a string "100E" but this still didn't work. Arduino returns "Reading: " + white space ! ??

Comment: Just to be clear **(1)** You're saying you can't run `parseInt` unless its in a `while` loop, and **(2)** you don't know how to close the while loop apart from an exit character `E` concatenated with the length of your `buff` array?  I'd like to direct your attention to http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/While where you'll notice `while (condition)` only loops while `(condition)` is true.  Ergo, you can exit the loop in the same way we did the `for` loop: `int k=0; while (k<15) { k++; }`  If exiting the loop is your concern, this is a proper way to do it.

Comment: Ta. 1) is right, because 2) I can't invent the condition to close the loop. I don't know the length of the array prior to receiving it, so I can't use your k<15 suggestion. So I followed http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ReadASCIIString using an array terminated with a newline in a 'while' loop, thinking I could send my data from Flash in that form, but I can't make that work yet. Got any better ideas than me for a condition to test for? Time passed seems dodgy. Know how to send an array terminated by a newline in flash, so it can be recognised by arduino code as such?

Comment: I totally missed the "arrays could be from 5 to 50" statement (my bad).  Admittedly, this would be easier if I could test the output of Serial.read(), regardless... as outlined by http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read, your condition could be the Serial.read() itself or some other exotic value; even your whitespace would work.  Since the method outputs `-1` when there is no data, you could write: `while (Serial.read() != -1) {`, or read once, store to a Boolean and reference that boolean in the condition: `boolean go = true; while (go) { buff[j] = Serial.parseInt(); if (buff[j] == -1) {go=false}}`

Comment: Putting Serial.read() where you suggest yields weirdly "ready to go
11
Reading: 
12
Reading: 
13
Reading: 
14
Reading: 
15
Reading: 
16

7

8

9

0
Reading: 
Reading: